# Gitlab Community running on docker - Heathcheck

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ce

I have a `docker container` running `gitlab community edition`.

It's working fine except that the container remains `unhealthty`

The problem comes from the `/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-healthcheck-rc` file.  It contains `url='http://localhost:80/gitlab/help'` and should be `url='http://myhostname:80/gitlab/help'`

If I change it, it's working.  But each time there is a `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`, it turns back to `localhost`

Indeed, in the log I can see

```
  * template[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-healthcheck-rc] action create
    - update content in file /opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-healthcheck-rc from 1e4e16 to 1a5b11
```

But where is `localhost` coming from ?  Is there a way to start the container with the right value ?

I treid adding a `hostname: myhostname` in the `docker-compose.yml` but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change that probably in `/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/gitlab-healthcheck.rb` as if nginx is enabled it seems that localhost is hardcoded

```
if node['gitlab']['nginx']['enable']
  ...
  host = "localhost:#{node['gitlab']['nginx']['listen_port']}"
end
```

Comment: Great it's working.  I modified the gitlab-healthcheck.rb file and mount it with the docker-compose.yml.  Thanks Jakub Bujny.